# APDS-9960 detected but not showing output on serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, hardware

I just bought an APDS-9960 sensor yesterday and tried it out today using Sparkfun's example from its APDS-9960 lib, and the only thing it printed out was:
"SparkFun APDS-9960 - ProximitySensor" twice then it didn't show any output
Using an Arduino Uno, and wires are connected correctly:

APDS :  Arduino Uno

VCC  :  3.3V

GND  :  GND

SDA  :  A4

SCL  :  SCL

INT  :  D2

I've also tried I2C scanning, and the device address was shown, but SparkFun's example code just didn't work at all.

[image: IRL Wiring Pic]

Using PCB terminals because another sensor will also be integrated into the Arduino Uno.

[image: I2C Scanner Output]

[image: SparkFun Program Output]

Code:

```
/****************************************************************
...
****************************************************************/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SparkFun_APDS9960.h>

// Global Variables
SparkFun_APDS9960 apds = SparkFun_APDS9960();
uint8_t proximity_data = 0;

void setup() {
  
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("------------------------------------"));
  Serial.println(F("SparkFun APDS-9960 - ProximitySensor"));
  Serial.println(F("------------------------------------"));
  
  // Initialize APDS-9960 (configure I2C and initial values)
  if ( apds.init() ) {
    Serial.println(F("APDS-9960 initialization complete"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during APDS-9960 init!"));
  }
  
  // Adjust the Proximity sensor gain
  if ( !apds.setProximityGain(PGAIN_2X) ) {
    Serial.println(F("Something went wrong trying to set PGAIN"));
  }
  
  // Start running the APDS-9960 proximity sensor (no interrupts)
  if ( apds.enableProximitySensor(false) ) {
    Serial.println(F("Proximity sensor is now running"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Something went wrong during sensor init!"));
  }
}

void loop() {
  
  // Read the proximity value
  if ( !apds.readProximity(proximity_data) ) {
    Serial.println("Error reading proximity value");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Proximity: ");
    Serial.println(proximity_data);
  }
  
  // Wait 250 ms before next reading
  delay(250);
}
```

I've tried putting `delay(100);` below `Serial.begin(9600);` as suggested here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/apds-9960-rgb-and-gesture-sensor-hookup-guide/discuss and it did not help.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I cannot see in your image, how exactly the jumper wires are attached to the proximity sensor board. Are you sure, that they have good and stable contact?

Comment: the picture shows that it printed more than what you said

Comment: Hey @chrisl! Thanks for the comment. The issue went away by itself, somehow, so I'm guessing it's the sensor or the board. Thanks anyways!